# Как получить значение элемента из xml-файла?

Tags: xml, qt, c++

После запроса:   http://apifree.forvo.com/key/bc78c6774d956410631a5c9ad27dd569/format/xml/action/word-pronunciations/word/hallo/language/de я получаю xml файл:

```
<items total="7">
<item>
<id>1053498</id>
<word>hallo</word>
<addtime>2011-03-11 01:29:50</addtime>
<hits>4705</hits>
<username>IchBinEs</username>
<sex>m</sex>
<country>Germany</country>
<code>de</code>
<langname>German</langname>
<pathmp3>  http://apifree.forvo.com/audio/1l2a223e361o31353c28323h2k363p3k2b2m3p342b2l1n373p2f1k281f2m2q261p2o1p313k383i3c2k2n39233q1h372f2q1f1g372b2a343n3k3i1g2h2b3n3k1k3b333a1n322h1m2g212q1o2a3h3q3i38282d3q3a2p211t1t_2k2n2g3d371l2q2c2937242j2m1b383i1b29282q37211t1t
</pathmp3>
...
```

Необходимо вывести значение элемента **pathmp3** ("http://apifree.forvo.com/audio/..."). Вот как я пытаюсь это сделать:

```
QString urlForXML = "http://apifree.forvo.com/key/bc78c6774d956410631a5c9ad27dd569/format/xml/action/word-pronunciations/word/hallo/language/de";

QNetworkAccessManager m_NetworkMngr;
QNetworkReply *reply = m_NetworkMngr.get(QNetworkRequest(urlForXML));
QEventLoop loop;
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),&loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();

QXmlStreamReader xmlReader;
xmlReader.addData(reply->readAll());

while(!xmlReader.atEnd())
{
    if (xmlReader.name() == "pathmp3")
      qDebug() << xmlReader.readElementText();

}
delete reply;
```

Но чтобы я не делал программа выводит пустоту. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Нужно учитывать [вложенность элементов](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/61031/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброго времени суток!

Ваша проблема в том, что Вы пытаетесь сравнить имя тега еще его не прочитав)))
В остальном вроде все верно)) Исправить надо строки:

> if (xmlReader.name() == "pathmp3")
>       qDebug() << xmlReader.readElementText();

В итоге должно получиться следующее:

```
// ...
QXmlStreamReader xmlReader;
xmlReader.addData(reply->readAll());

while(!xmlReader.atEnd()) // пока не конец потока...
{
   xml.readNextStartElement(); // читаем следующий открывающий элемент (тег)
   if (xmlReader.name() == "pathmp3") // если имя элемента "pathmp3"
        qDebug() << xmlReader.readElementText(); // что-то делаем с текстом...

}
// ...
```

Успехов!